# Acceder a los contactos del Móvil

Tags: java, android

estoy realizando una app que accede a los contactos del teléfono móvil y los muestra, pero quiero mostrarlos organizados por tipo, ya sea Persona, Trabajo, Casa, Fax laboral, etc.

de esta forma los obtengo todos y funciona a la perfección pero el problema esta que no he encontrado la forma de obtenerlos por los tipos anteriormente mencionados.

Aquí les dejo el código de lo que he realizado, Muchas Gracias

```
TextView contactos_home = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactos_home);

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String contactos = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
        contactos_home.append(contactos);
        contactos_home.append("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondiendo mi pregunta.

```
String [] datosMostrar = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE};
String seleccionClause = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + "='2' AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IS NOT NULL";
String orden = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            datosMostrar,
            seleccionClause,
            null,
            orden);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        contactos_home.append(" Tipo: " +cursor.getString(2));
        contactos_home.append("\n");
    }
```

Aquí les dejo la tabla con la constante de los principales tipos de contactos

```
TYPE_CUSTOM -- Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)
TYPE_HOME   -- Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
TYPE_MOBILE -- Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)
TYPE_WORK   -- Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)
TYPE_FAX_WORK -- Constant Value: 4 (0x00000004)
TYPE_FAX_HOME  --Constant Value: 5 (0x00000005)
```

Para obtener un tipo especifico solo tiene que cambiar la compraración en la variable (seleccionClause) (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + "='**2**')

Answer (score 1):

El tercer atributo permite filtrar. Se pueden añadir más de un elemento de ordenación si se separan los elementos con comas. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, 
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID };

String filter = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " NOT LIKE ''";
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, filter, null, null);
```

Deberías cambiar los atributos del ejemplo por tus atributos.

Comment: Creo que no me explique bien, cuando insertas un contacto nuevo en el teléfono y pones el número puedes poner si es (Persona, Trabajo, Casa, Fax laboral, etc). Pero como quiero obtener los contactos es por ejemplo. Solo los que el tipo sea (Trabajo) o solo los del tipo (Persona).

Comment: Ha ok. Pues borro mi respuesta

Comment: No la borres cualquier ayuda siempre es bienvenida, fui yo que no me explique bien, ya encontré la solución y les deje por si alguien la necesita. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El último parámetro es el ordenamiento (sortOrder) en base a eso puedes obtener los contactos, por ejemplo si deseas un ordenamiento por nombre de persona define `ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME`, es importante que el segundo paramnetro :

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

Para obtener datos especificos debes revisar las tablas y definir en base a que dato deseas ordenar tus resultados:

- [ContactsContract.Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html?hl=es)
- [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html?hl=es)
- [ContactsContract.RawContacts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html?hl=es)
- [ContactsContract.Contacts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html?hl=es)
- [ContactsContract.Groups](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html?hl=es)
- [ContactsContract.StatusUpdates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html?hl=es)
- [ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html?hl=es)
- [ContactsContract.Settings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html?hl=es)
- [ContactsContract.SyncState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html?hl=es)
- [ContactsContract.PhoneLookup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html?hl=es)